# Cannot file copy and move coding between map & unmap network drive?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Hi, I just write map & unmap access to network drive. Coding is working properly. But, When I write the file moving coding during these, got issue "Could Not File Path". And then cannot create a map network drive. I have no idea now.

Could I get any idea from all. Thank in advance

```
Protected Sub btnMOVE_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMOVE.Click

        Dim SourceFile As String = "D:\file.txt"
        Dim DestinationFile As String = "Y:\MoveFile.txt"

        MapDrive("T")
        System.IO.File.Move(SourceFile, DestinationFile)
        UnMapDrive("T")
 End Sub
```

Comment: You've D: as the source and Y: as the destination. What's T doing? What's MapDrive? What line does the error occur on? Can you give the full error type and message?

Comment: T is for Map Drive. I got the issue System.IO.File.Move(SourceFile, DesitinationFile). I get "Could not file path" Error message. can i give me any idea.